# jQuery infinite ajax scroll trigger/offset issue

Tags: jquery, plugins, containers, offset, infinite-scroll

I use this infinite scroll plugin [jQuery ias](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) which is really well documented and is working perfectly in the most cases.

The problem is, that the following pages are loaded before scroll to the bottom of the container. I need them loaded when the bottom has reached.

This is my jquery part:

```
jQuery.ias({
    container : '.con',
    item: '.row',
    pagination: ".findopaginator",
    next: "a.flPageNext",
    loader: '<img src="/layout/cyt/img/pageloader.gif">',
    history: false,
    loaderDelay: 1000,
    thresholdMargin: 500, //this is important
    triggerPageThreshold: 3,
    trigger: "Nächste 30 Artikel werden geladen...",
    onRenderComplete: function(items) {...}
});
```

thresholdMargin:

> On default IAS starts loading new items when you scroll to the latest
>   .item element. The thresholdMargin will be added to the items' offset,
>   giving you the ability to load new items earlier (please note that the
>   margin should be a negative integer for this case).

But a positive value does not work.

Maybe somebody had the same problem and has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `thresholdMargin` is greater then the sum (item height + item offset) it will never reach it. I think this is something the plugin could handle in the future, but until then you have to calculate it yourself.

Comment: I did it myself and edited your script a little bit. thank you for this great plugin!